# How to update forked repo from GitHub Web?

Tags: github, fork, repository

I want to update a forked repo from GitHub web interface.

I tried a few things from other questions but it gave me `fatal: not a git repo` when I use `git remote add upstream git://blabla`

Comment: You want to update the upstream link on the github web page? Sorry, there is no option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an https address first, as mentioned in [GitHub FAQ](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo):

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
# if upstream already exist
git remote set-url upstream https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
```

And make sure of the case used in this address (it is case-sensitive, and the slightest error will give you "`not a git repo`").

Comment: Is it possible in Web interface? I made some progress in console. I typed wrong remote url. How can I change it? It gives "remote url already exist"

Comment: @Imrahil use `git remote set-url`: see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote. That will allow you to update/replace the url associated with a remote.